# jquery .append trims the spaces automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to append new data to the container div using jquery .append() function. But, the output appended trims the spaces between the labels created. Check the screenshot attached:[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Javascript and HTML code are given below:

```js
$("a.add-member").click(function(){
  var user = '<div class="row user">'+
      '<div class="col-md-6">abc@site.com</div>'+
      '<div class="col-md-4">'+
      '<div class="user-roles">'+
      '<span class="label label-user-role">Role 1</span>'+
      '<span class="label label-user-role">Role 2</span>'+
      '<span class="label label-user-role active">Role 3</span>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="col-md-2 text-center">'+
      '<a href="#" class="remove-member"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';
  $("#add-team .users").append(user).hide(0).fadeIn(700);
});
```

```html
<div class="users">
  <div class="row user">
    <div class="col-md-6">xyz@site.com</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="user-roles">
        <span class="label label-user-role">Role 1</span>
        <span class="label label-user-role">Role 2</span>
        <span class="label label-user-role active">Role 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
      <a href="#" class="remove-member"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row user">
    <div class="col-md-6">pqr@site.com</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="user-roles">
        <span class="label label-user-role">Role 1</span>
        <span class="label label-user-role">Role 2</span>
        <span class="label label-user-role active">Role 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
      <a href="#" class="remove-member"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are no spaces in your jQuery. That's probably the problem.

Comment: Remove the spaces from your original HTML and use `padding` or `margin`. The width of spaces are unreliable, as they will change between browsers and OS.

Comment: But, I haven't entered any spaces in HTML too. Still it works perfectly.
Why not the jquery then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added spaces in jQuery code:

```
$("a.add-member").click(function(){
    var user = '<div class="row user">'+
                    '<div class="col-md-6">ajinkya.bandagale@gmail.com</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                        '<div class="user-roles">'+
                            '<span class="label label-user-role">Admin</span> '+
                            '<span class="label label-user-role">Observer</span> '+
                            '<span class="label label-user-role active">Normal</span> '+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2 text-center">'+
                        '<a href="#" class="remove-member"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
    $("#add-team .users").append(user).hide(0).fadeIn(700);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have written your code in HTML in different line for each span but when you add div or anything in through jQuery by creating a string it consider it as a single line. 
So if you add \n at each line it will work.

```
user = '<div class="row user">' +
                '<div class="col-md-6">pqr@site.com</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-4">' +
                '<div class="user-roles">' +
                '<span class="label label-user-role">Role 1</span>\n' +
                '<span class="label label-user-role">Role 2</span>\n ' +
                '<span class="label label-user-role active">Role 3</span>\n ' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-2 text-center">' +
                '<a href="#" class="remove-member"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';
                $(".users").append(user).hide(0).fadeIn(700);
```